# Triggering click on type=file with another button causes unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I'm trying to create my own "upload" button instead of the default one. By clicking on my custom button I'm triggering a click on the original upload button:

HTML:

```
 <form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="api/upload.php" method="POST">
     <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5120000" />
     <input name="userfile" type="file" class="choose-file"/>
     <button class="choose-picture"></button>
     <input type="submit" class="send-button" value='' />
 </form>
```

JS:

```
$('.choose-picture').click(function() {
    $('.choose-file').trigger('click');
});
```

I have another script that displays the picture that got uploaded when I click the submit button. If I use the original upload file button, nothing happens and that's ok (the picture is only suppose to show up after I choose and submit one), but when I click my custom (.choose-picture) button it acts as if I already chose a file for uploading, putting some mess in the img source and displaying a non-img (the icon you see when the source is wrong).

This is what the console says:

```
GET http://localhost/OrlenOla/%3Cbr%20/%3E%3Cb%3ENotice%3C/b%3E:%20%20Undefined…api/upload.php%3C/b%3E%20on%20line%20%3Cb%3E10%3C/b%3E%3Cbr%20/%3Euploads/ 403 (Forbidden)
```

So it's acting as if I already called my upload script (which I have no intention to call at this stage as it's supposed to happen on submit).

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't explicitly specify a `type` attribute on a `<button>` element, it's treated as though you explicitly declared it as `type="submit"` (i.e. a button that's intended to submit the form):

> submit: The button submits the form data to the server. **This is the default if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.**
>   
> <sub>[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)</sub>

That's why it's triggering your form submit event handler code, because it *does* submit the form.

Easiest way to fix this is to just specify `type="button"` on the element:

```
<button type="button" class="choose-picture"></button>
```

The other way (as you discovered) is to prevent the default behaviour of the button:

```
$('.choose-picture').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.choose-file').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: I just posted my own solution, but I accept yours as it makes perfect sense, thank you for explaining why it's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.choose-picture').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    $('.choose-file').trigger('click');
    });
});
```